# How to get textbox value? that exsist in input tag but not in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox which is empty, but when i inspected, it has following html:

`<input data-bind="value: optionName, namePath: true" id="QuestionOptions_0__Text" name="QuestionOptions[0].Text" onkeyup="AddToGroupOption(this.id);" type="text" value="Male"></input>`

I am trying to get value of textbox as:

`$('#QuestionOptions_0__Text').val()`

and

`$('#QuestionOptions_0__Text').attr('value')`

but it always returns `""`
How can i get the value,
Plz guide me,
Thanx

Comment: It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/8GMCB/

Comment: it's working 
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/RTMdX/

Comment: check if id of input is unique or not and check for console errors also.

Comment: An incidental issue, but `input` is a self-closing tag.  It should be `<input />` not `<input></input>`

Comment: I have mentioned that my textbox is empty. . .but in html it shows the value and i am trying to access the value in document.getready function

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Id is unique and there is no console errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I have found the solution, I can access the value by:
`$('#QuestionOptions_0__Text').prop('defaultValue')`